# Controlling (firewall) trafic to docker/docker-compose network

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

I'm running docker a machine that server various services. I want to control these services using iptables or preferably using ufw (as I'm not that skilled with iptables itself).

In my previous setup, I used "vanilla" docker which uses a virtual interface called "docker0" to route network traffic through containers. I successfully "googled" a solution to make the firewall work described in this article: https://svenv.nl/unixandlinux/dockerufw (note: even though I wrote the article, it's just a sum of internet knowledge merged together).

One of the things the I found was this piece:

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING ! -o docker0 -s 172.17.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

Which (I assume) makes sure everything goes into docker0 properly.

Now I've change my setup and started using "docker-compose" which spins up docker containers automatically in an isolated network. Once again, docker uses a virtual device for this which is named after the id of the network:

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                            DRIVER              SCOPE
(...)             
207a57fc0080        dockeropenvpndata_network-vpn   bridge              local               
(...)
```

and...

```
$ ifconfig | grep 207a57fc0080
br-207a57fc0080 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:ce:c5:81:04
```

I *assume* that changing the iptables config posted above to the new network device *might* solve the problem:

```
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING ! -o br-207a57fc0080 -s 172.17.0.0/16 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
```

However I have no idea how to test this.

- The interface's name (network id) seems to be (pseudo) random
- The interface's name (network id) is only known after `docker-compose up`
- As far as I know the rule is applied at boot time, when the id is still unknown.

In short, I'm looking for a way to firewall my docker machine again. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: No the above post routing rule does not controll the traffic that goes to docker. It just masquerades the traffic that goes out to the host network (or internet), which means your containers can access internet/host network.

Comment: You question is not clear enough! You said you did something but I didn't understand what exactly you're going to do.

Comment: Thx for the info, basically, I just want to be able to use a firewall. Docker doesnt't listen to my firewall and bypasses it:(

Comment: If there is anything I can to further clear this out, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the configuration in `/etc/default/docker` is not taken into account when using systemd, resulting in `--iptables=false` not being set.

The docker options for systemd are specified in the service file in `/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`. Entries in this file can be overridden by adding/adjusting the drop-in file in `cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf`

I add the drop-in file with these contents:

```
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/default/docker
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --iptables=false -H fd://
```

(The first empty ExecStart= is actually required)

This starts docker without the iptables configuration and makes the original steps (see link in the original question) work again.